# Why is the interface WebSecurityExpressionHandler in spring security deprecated?

Tags: spring-security

I was asking why the `WebSecurityExpressionHandler`is annotated deprecated in spring security 3.1 and 3.2? There is no documentation in the api.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebSecurityExpressionHandler.html

Does anybody know something about the reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they are going to replace `WebSecurityExpressionHandler` with `SecurityExpressionHandler<T>` where `T` can be either `FilterInvocation` or `MethodInvocation`. Note that it doesn't affect implementation classes (`DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler`).

**See also:**

- [SEC-1562 Create SecurityExpressionHandler interface](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1562)

Comment: Ah ok I see. Changed the interface and it works as before. Thanks!